# Understanding a formula from Stewart's "Calculus: Early Transcendentals" on related rates

Tags: calculus, geometry, proof-explanation

This question comes from section 3.11 of the textbook mentioned in the title.

> A hemispherical tank with a radius of $10$m is filled from an inflow pipe at a rate of $3$ cubic meters per minute. How fast is the water level rising when the water level is $5$m from the bottom of the tank? (Hint: the volume of a cap of thickness $h$ sliced from a sphere of radius $r$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}h^2(3r-h)$).

There's a second part of the question that is stated as follows:

> What is the rate of change of the area of the exposed surface of the water when the water is $5$m deep?

I have the answer for the second part from an official solution guide. It is as follows:

Set up a triangle with a base of $r$ (representing the radius of the surface of the water) and a height of $10-h$ (where $h$ is the height of the water). Then the hypotenuse is the radius of the sphere: $10$. By application of the Pythagorean theorem, we can find that $r=5\sqrt{3}$ when $h=5$. Then, differentiating $r^2+(10-h)^2+10^2$, we get $r\frac{dr}{dt}+h\frac{dh}{dt}=10\frac{dh}{dt}$. Then we need to solve for $\frac{dr}{dt}$ to plug in for $\frac{dA}{dt}=2\pi r\frac{dr}{dt}$.

My issue arises at this point in the solution. The book claims that $\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{1}{25\pi}$. It is clear to me that this should be solved for in the first part of the problem and that this solution comes from differentiating $V(t)=\frac{\pi}{3}(h(t))^2(3r-h(t))$. What I don't understand is where this formula comes from. They seems to be using $h$ to mean two different things. First, it is defined to be the thickness of the tank. But then it is used as a function of time representing the height of the water. This makes me think that the hint is just poorly worded, and that this is simply a formula for the volume of a hemisphere. But this also doesn't make sense, as this volume would be given by $\frac{\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3}{2}$. These don't appear to be equivalent formulas. To further add to the confusion, the hint would seem to imply that the radius from the center to the *outside* of the tank is $10$m, but a figure included in the book shows this measurement as being from the center to the *inside* of the tank.

If there's anything I can do to clarify my issue, let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In that formula $h$ is the height of the [spherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap), so the word "thickness" is not really appropriate.

Comment: @Aretino Excellent, thank you.